# Is karate mock supports "contains" syntax for match condition?

Tags: karate

Does karate mock supports `contains` syntax to match a certain condition?

I have a requirement like if `Account Id` contains `"789"` then send the required response file.

I have tried, but facing syntax issue.

```
def RespFile = (AccountId == "909090" ? 
  'Failure.xml' : 
  (AccountId contains ["359"] ? 'Succes.xml' : 'nomatch.xml'))
```

Please help me for the above

Answer (score 0):

No. Use pure JS logic. Or you can try look at the [`karate.match()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-match) API.

Something like this:

```
* def accountId = 'some string'
* def response = accountId.contains('foo') ? read('foo.json') : {}
```

Comment: It worked, but our is a xml file so first we converted it to a string and used the above syntax so finally worked